# Bind image sequence to scroll event

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll

I have a `div` with some stacked images inside. The scroll event should control the images shown. So I don't want to start an animation when the user scrolls, I want to change the pictures depending on the scroll position.

I really have difficulties wrapping my head around that, but my idea was to count the images, get the height of the page and then divide the number of images through the height of the pages. That way I could define "regions" for the frames - but I have no idea if that would work.

Are there any best practices for this technique? How does it work?

This is the code I have so far - primitively simple: http://jsfiddle.net/mxQd8/1/

Comment: @PitaJ No, thats one thing I forgot - actually it needs to be fixed, or even more elegant, scrolled a bit with parallax scrolling.

Comment: You'll run into difficulty with that approach if all the images aren't the same height - you're better off using something like offsetTop to get each element's position relative to the parent. Are you using a plugin to capture the scroll event?

Comment: @CodeMoose No, at the moment I am just using `$(window).scroll` but I just noticed that this is not that cool because the attached functions fires after the event is completed. Also I have some problems to iterate through the images. If I post some code, do you think you could help me?

Comment: @Sven let's see what you've got. If I can give you a short answer, I'll post it here - if not, we should move this over to chat

Comment: Also, see this plugin - https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel - I've used this in the past to grab mousewheel events mid-scroll, should suit your purposes well

Comment: @CodeMoose I just attached a Fiddle of what I got so far - the problems should be obvious. Using `:eq(x)` that way without a loop or something isn't right.

Comment: Ah, I understand what you're trying to do now. I'll poke at it and let you know what I find out.

Comment: Want to make sure I understand this right - you're looking to show a different image based on scroll wheel movement, right? There's no actual vertical position change?

Comment: Or are you trying to increment the animation based on the page height?

Comment: @CodeMoose No I think you understood it right! I am amazed how fast you got to this solution! Now I am trying to implement  `setTimeout`. The only thing that I dislike about the mousewheel plugin is that it does not support touch devices at all. http://www.nike.com/jumpman23/aj2012/mobile/ on that page they somehow managed to play an animation while the user scrolls - normally the scroll event is fired after the user scrolled (on iOS/iPhone/mobile Safari). Do you have any idea how that could work?

Comment: jQuery Mobile offers the ability to detect scrollStart and scrollStop, but you can't determine the direction. This is probably a good time to close the question and ask the community for a mobile library with scroll direction detection ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to upload the mousewheel plugin to a fiddle so I can't demonstrate directly. The code you're going to want is along these lines:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var container = $('#container'),
    // # of pictures
        nImg = 0;    // active picture
        imgNum = $('#container img').length;

    container.mousewheel(function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) {
        if(deltaY>0){
             nImg++;   
        }else{
             nImg--;   
        }
        if(nImg>=imgNum){ nImg = 0; }
        if(nImg<0){ nImg = imgNum-1; }

        $(".animated").each(function(){ $(this).removeClass("show") });
        $(".animated").eq(nImg).addClass("show");
    });
});
```

Basically, you only need to test if deltaY on the scroll is negative or positive (up scroll or down scroll). Based on that, you show the next or previous image.

This will scroll very rapidly - you might need to create a `setTimeout` to lock the scroll for 250/500 ms, depending on how fast you want the animation to go. It will also loop - you'll have to write something a little different if you don't want it to loop. I have to jump into a meeting, but I hope this gets you started - let me know if I can do anything else to help!

Answer (score 0):

I've written a jQuery plugin for exactly this problem: Take a look at [jQuery Transe](http://github.com/yckart/jquery.transe.js).

Comment: Yes please, I'm interesting in seeing it!